# Intel Fortran to calculate hyerbolic function with complex argument

Tags: arguments, fortran, intel, complex-numbers, intrinsics

As shown on the official document:
[COSH](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/511564)

Intel Fortran does not allow users to input complex argument into hyperbolic cosine function. So what is the alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortran 2008 allows complex argument. Some compilers already allow this. If your does not (as, e.g., ifort 15.0), compute it using `exp()`.

```
cosh(x) = ( exp(x) + exp(-x) ) / 2
```

or use the identity

```
cosh(x+iy) = cosh(x) * cos(y) + i * sinh(x) * sin(y)
```